# Configure Virtualbox to have my vm appear in intranet

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am running WinXP inside Virtualbox that runs on Win2003. Now internet-access (and also intranet) from the vm worked straight out of the box, so to say - but now I would like to assign an IP to the VM so that I can access it from other computers in the intranet as if it was ordinary metal...

But neither Google nor the manual have had instructions for semi-dummy users which would have enabled me to set this up :(

Could anyone share a few essential steps (or URLs), pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the networked adapter in bridged mode (as opposed to NAT) in the vbox config, and set the IP from within the vm.

Comment: Interesting - I did that and lost the conncetion to the server which runs VirtualBox. Will look at it tomorrow (when I'm back in the office)...

Comment: Thanks Mark, that did it. Unfortunately now I'm no longer seeing my server in the net (nor can I connect to the web from the server when the VM is running), I guess something needs fixing in the ip config. Will check other questions or post another thread for that...

Comment: You're not giving the VM the same IP as the host right? The VM should be treated as a separate machine.

Comment: No, I have not assigned an IP to the VM, but looking in its ipconfig, it got a different IP.